# Cannot explain why std::istream_iterator set std::ios_base in error state

Tags: c++

I am trying to conert a vector into a stream and back.
While the first part works without issues, the last line of the following code put std::ios_base is an error state. Have you got any idea why it is so?
Apparently myVecOut is equal to myVec after the code executes....

```
    std::vector<double> myVec( 3 );
    std::stringstream temp;
    std::copy(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(temp, " "));
    std::cout << temp.str() << std::endl;
    std::vector<double> myVecOut;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<double>(temp), std::istream_iterator<double>(), std::back_inserter(myVecOut));
```

Comment: I think it is because of all the stds.

Comment: What are the input data?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363581/input-stream-iterators-and-exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's set into `fail` state, because `copy` does not know how many items to read. It reads as long as the stream is in a <strike>`.good()`</strike> non-`.fail()` state. While skipping the last space, it hits the end, and sets both `eof` (because it tried to read beyond the end) and `fail` (because it could not read the double it wanted to).

Call `.clear()` afterwards to clear those error bits.

---

The difference between the iterators comparing non-equal while `.good()` is true and while `.fail()` is false is that `istream_iterator` will still advance even if the stream is in an `eof` state. The following further examines it:

```
std::stringstream a;
a << "1.1 2.2";
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<double>(a), std::istream_iterator<double>(),
          std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
```

Now, after we read "2.2", the `eof` state is set (because it tried to read beyond "2"). But the begin and end iterator won't yet compare equal, because the `fail` state is not set, and thus `.fail()` does not return true (while `.good()` would have returned false, because it considers `.eof()` in addition). Only after the next read, when it could not read another double anymore, the `fail` state is set, and *then* the iterators compare equal, and the loop within `std::copy` exits.